# Example of dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Provide an example of an infinity of dense subsets of a space $(X,d)$ such that the intersection of all of them is not a dense subset.

I have tried taking $(\mathbb{Q}, d_{usual})$ and as dense subsets the intervals $(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), ...$

But it seems to me that it does not work, since the lock of each one of the subsets is not the $\mathbb{Q}$ and with this it would not be true that they are dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, take $A_x=\mathbb{Q}-\{x\}$.

Comment: Excuse me, to take this, would you have to take as $X = \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes, I took $X=\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual metric, but you can take $X=\mathbb{R}$ as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information

Comment: excuse me why is the intersection not dense?

Comment: Because it is the empty set.

Comment: An apology, I have already verified that each of the sets is connected in that way. It is very evident to me that its intersection is empty, but I have not been able to prove it, I have really tried, could you help me with it please.

Comment: Suppose that an element $y$ is in the intersection of all $\mathbb{R}-\{x\}$, then $y$ must be different from $x$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, thus such a $y$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X= (0,\infty)$ with the usual metric. For $p$ a prime, define $D_p$ be the set of quotients $n/p^k,$ where $n\in \mathbb N$ and $p$ are relatively prime, and $k\in\mathbb N.$ Then each $D_p$ is dense in $X$ and the collection $\{D_p\}$ is pairwise disjoint.